# Decode JSON file with Kotlin vs Swift

Tags: android, json, kotlin, decode

JSON decoding was improved in Swift4

you simply just call JSONDecoder().decode
and give it the json object and it will be converted into object

here is an example of that way

https://roadfiresoftware.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-4/

my question that is there a way in Kotlin similar to the new way in Swift4 ?

Comment: You will have to use some sort of libraries to parse JSON, for instance you can make use of [Gson] (https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Android has had that for quite a few years now.

It's a library from Google themselves, called GSON:
https://github.com/google/gson

Example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
gson.fromJson("MY JSON STRING", MyClass.class);
```

There are many overloads for the 'fromJson' function. There is also a 'toJson' function, to turn an object into a JSON string.

This is not just for Kotlin, it also works in Java.